# Did I get the right answer for this Macaulay's method question?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I had to calculate the deflection at the right-hand side, (x = 5).
Taking my cut at the right end of the beam after the final change in loading conditions my expression for the moment M is:

$$M - 3[x-4]^2 + 12[x-3] - 12[x-3] = 0$$

$$M = 3[x-4]^2$$

after integrating twice:
$$EIV = -\frac{[x-4]^4}{4} + c_0x +c_1$$

Boundary conditions : V(1) = 0, v(3) = 0

$c1 = 0, c0 = 0 $

$M = -[x-4]^4/4$

$v(5) = 1/7 X -(5-4)^4/4  $
$v(5) = -0.035714 m$ deflection at $x = 5 $

Is this right?

[image]

Comment: Let's check your equation M = 3[x-4]^2, at x = 0, M = 3(0-4)^2 = 48, and at x = 5, M = 3(5-4)^2 = 3, are these moments correct?

Answer (score 1):

The graph below contains the keys required to solve this problem.

[image]

Your moment equation obviously was a mistake because it does not satisfy the tests at the boundary points, at which (free edge) the moment must be zero. Please try the procedure outlined below to solve this problem.

First, you shall find the support reactions; then write the equation for the moment from the left end (x = 0) towards the right (x = 5); then integrate once to get the equation for slope, and integrate again to get the deflection.

Note that the deflection of joint 6 can't be obtained from the derived equation because there exists a discontinuity - the shape of deflection from point 4 to point 5 is a curved line, beyond point 5, it becomes a straight line, as there is no force over this segment except the beam self-weight, which is ignored in this problem.

**Hint:** *You can write the moment equation for the segments between points 2 & 5, then use geometry to work out the deflection of joint 6.*

**Additional Information:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you seem to have confused what goes where. I got:

$$M = -\frac{6\frac{kN}{m}}{2} \langle x-2\rangle^2+ 12 kN \langle x-3\rangle^1 +\frac{6\frac{kN}{m}}{2} \langle x-4\rangle^2$$

and after the integrations I got:

$$c_1= \frac{1}{6}, c_2 =0$$

I'm not providing the rest because it looks like homework.

**UPDATE**:
Contrary to other answers I believe the deflection would have a shape like

**[image: strong text]**

i.e. at 2 m from the left end there will be no abrupt change in slope (it will be gradual.